# How to create a textbox that has decimal value

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add a textbox in my application that starts showing with the value `0.00` just like a ATM, as you type the numbers then it keeps the two decimal point until satisfied with the value for example the sequence to end up of a value of `1023.00` would be (as I type)

```
0.01
0.10
1.02
10.23
102.30
1023.00
```

Is this possible to do in a windows forms application?. I am just not sure how to go about it.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms Format TextBox To Currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258562/winforms-format-textbox-to-currency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this kind of scenario I would not use a textbox, but a label or a read-only textbox. To get the user input just use the [key-press](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event on your form (you have to enable [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) on the form too) - then just remember the keys/numbers pressed and output the format you are targeting - should be a rather easy algorithm ([Char.IsNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx), and [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) might come in handy):

```
    private int _inputNumber = 0;
    private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) return;
        _inputNumber = 10*_inputNumber + Int32.Parse(e.KeyChar.ToString());
        ReformatOutput();
    }

    private void ReformatOutput()
    {
         myOutput.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", (double)_inputNumber / 100.0);
    }
```

Note: Why not use a textbox - because it's internal logic with select/replace/remove/type is so overcomplicated that the cases you would have to check are just to much to handle gracefully - so instead of trying to change a cannon into a sling you should start with the sling.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can use those functions in a user control that is in the form?

Comment: Yes I think that should work too, but the KeyPreview might be an issue if you cannot get a focus on your usercontrol - just try a bit.

Comment: Yeah it works... the only issue i have now is that i have to click somewhere in the form when i arrive at that screen for the numbers to start populating...

Comment: you should be able to remove this issue by setting the focus to something in Form_Load

Comment: I see that you are multiplying with 10, how do you implement delete?